Org Babel with language with angle brackets in use
I wanted to write an Org Babel file with some CUDA code, where they use the <<<...>>> syntax in the language. This confuses Org Babel because it's the syntax for including code blocks (which is a feature I'd like to use). Is there a work-around for this?

You can customize org-babel-noweb-wrap-start and org-babel-noweb-wrap-end to be something other than the default << and >> resp. Untested, so I don't have any suggestions about what to use, but the fact that they are customizable should give you some hope that it is doable.

The markers for noweb blocks are stored in customizable variables: org-babel-noweb-wrap-start (by default <<) and org-babel-noweb-wrap-end (by default >>).
We change these markers for this file only by using an Emacs feature, File Local Variables, as shown below, to double back-and forward-ticks (which works for this example, but which one might have to experiment with in more general cases).Note that this section must be at the end of your Org mode file:
* File local variables                                                   :noexport
# Local Variables:
# org-babel-noweb-wrap-start: "``"
# org-babel-noweb-wrap-end: "''"
# End:

That way, the CUDA <<<1, 1>>> construct cannot be confused with the noweb construct which now will look like this:  ``NOWEB-ID''.
We can then break up the basic CUDA example into two blocks, one for the function add that is to be done on the GPU(s) and one for the main function.
Here's the add block:
#+name: add
#+begin_src C++
  #include <iostream>
  #include <math.h>
  // Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
  __global__
  void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
  }

#+end_src

and here's the main block which includes the add block using noweb with the modified markers:
#+nmae: main
#+begin_src C++ :tangle yes :noweb yes
  // Noweb will replace the following with the code in the `add' block above.
  ``add''      

  int main(void)
  {
    int N = 1<<20;
    float *x, *y;

    // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

    // initialize x and y arrays on the host
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      x[i] = 1.0f;
      y[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU.
    // The special CUDA notation will be left alone.
    add<<<1, 1>>>(N, x, y);

    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(x);
    cudaFree(y);
    
    return 0;
  }
#+end_src

If you tangle the main block with C-c C-v C-t, and check the resulting .cpp file, you will see that it is identical to the basic CUDA example file: noweb included the add block into the output file and it did not touch the <<<1, 1>>> special CUDA notation.
I don't have CUDA installed, so I can't run the example, but the tangling test succeeds and that should be enough: I see no reason why running it would not work.
